# How to open image from mysql database?

Tags: java, mysql, blob

I can store an image in mySql database whose datatype was blob. I have stored the image in binary image format. I have stored the image in MYSQL with the help of this code

```
File file = new File("G:/photos/New Folder (2)/bhavana_gallery_10.jpg");

            byte[] bFile = new byte[(int) file.length()];

            try {

             FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

             fileInputStream.read(bFile);

             fileInputStream.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {

             e.printStackTrace();

            }




    inpatient.setImagefile(bFile);
```

but i can open image in web application , can i any conversion need , what type conversion please tell me .........

Comment: u stored it in mysqldb, but are accessing it through filesystem?

Comment: **yes, i stored successfully but i can't open this file system , how can i open binay image into file system , any need conversion **

Answer (score 0):

Your file path have spaces('New Folder (2)').
Change this fold's name to 'NewFolder' or the other without spaces